# AngularJs elements not showing up in print dialogue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, printing

I have a page showing up blank when I open up the print Dialogue. The page is comprised mostly of AngularJS elements. I am am calling up the print dialogue with:

```
<a href=""onclick="window.print(); return false;"> Print </a>
```

The only thing I see on this page is this print button. I don't see any of the tables generated with `ng-repeat` whatsoever. Is this a problem with AngularJS? If so how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle which reproduces the problem?

Answer (score -2):

If your using AngularJS:

```
<a href="" ng-click="window.print(); return false;"> Print </a>
```

Second, since it is not a link, you should wrap it in a button instead like:

```
<button ng-click="window.print(); return false;"> Print </button>
```

Comment: Does not work with error: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'false' is an unexpected token at column 23 of the expression [window.print();return false;] starting at [false;].